# Temporizador Discord Bot

Tags: javascript, nodejs, setinterval, async, countdowntimer

tengo la siguiente duda con mi código que dejare más abajo, no entiendo ¿porque ocurre este problema?, si imprimo por consola mi temporizador, veo que todo va perfecto, pero a la hora de imprimir en el canal de discord, este tiene un defase cada 5 segundos aproximadamente.

```
client2.on('message', async message => {

    let minute = 1;
    let second = 60;

    duracion = toMilli(minute,second);

    try{    
        if(message.content === '-start'){


                temporizador_channel.messages.fetch().then((results) => {
                    temporizador_channel.bulkDelete(results);
                })
                //Sección de mensaje Embed para "RONDA INICIADA"
                    embed_msj = new MessageEmbed()
                        .setTitle("RONDA INICIADA")
                        .setColor(0x338aff)
                        .setDescription("("+minute+" minutos), SUERTE PARA TOD@S...!!!")
                        .addField("Aviso: ","Para visualizar el tiempo, por favor entrar a la sala de #temporizador.",true)
                        .setImage("https://i.imgflip.com/1ift34.jpg");
                    //     // channel_remote_duel.send(embed_msj);
                        prueba_tiempo.send(embed_msj);
                        minute--;
                        duracion = toMilli(minute,second);

                    //Fin de sección
                    // mensaje = await prueba_tiempo.send('Tiempo: '+zfill(minute,2)+' : '+zfill(second,2));    
                // for(i=duracion;duracion>0;i--){
                    const timeCheck = async ()=>{

                        try{
                        
                            const segundos_rest = Math.max(0,((Date.now() / 1000) + (duracion * 60))-(Date.now() / 1000));    
                            // const mensaje = await prueba_tiempo.send(getTime());
                            // mensaje = await prueba_tiempo.send(fromMilli(duracion));

                            if(segundos_rest === 0){
                                clearIntervalAsync(timeCheck);
                                mensaje.delete({timeout: 100});
                                console.log('Date: '+(Date.now()/1000)+', segundos_rest: '+segundos_rest+', duracion: '+duracion);
                                // prueba_tiempo.send('SE ACABO EL TIEMPO');
                            }

                            second--;
                            duracion = toMilli(minute,second);
                            valor = ((Date.now() / 1000) + (duracion * 60))-(Date.now() / 1000);
                            // await mensaje.edit(fromMilli(valor/60));
                            mensaje.edit(fromMilli(valor/60));
                            console.log(fromMilli(valor/60)+' segundos restantes: '+segundos_rest);
                        
                        }catch(error){
                            console.error(error)
                        }
                    }
                        
                // }        
                duracion = toMilli(minute,second);
                valor = ((Date.now() / 1000) + (duracion * 60))-(Date.now() / 1000);
                
                mensaje = await prueba_tiempo.send(fromMilli(duracion));
            
            setInterval(timeCheck,900);
        } 

        if(message.content === '-stop'){
            clearInterval(timeCheck);
            prueba_tiempo.send('TIEMPO DETENIDO');
            
        }

        
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
})
```

y el resultado en el canal es lo siguiente:

01:59
01:58
01:57
01:56
01:55.. .. luego aqui se queda como pegado por 5 segundos.. y luego continua
01:54
... y asi sucesivamente.. pero por consola.. todo va bien, asi que no entiendo que ocurra? Por favor espero puedan ayudarme, por un lado, soy nuevo con esto de los Bots de Discord, asi que espero me puedan explicar bien como si fuera niño de 5 años jeje

Comment: Una cosa es la ejecución del código de forma local, donde la salida en consola ea casi inmediata y otra es el envío de datos mediante paquetes hacia un canal de Discord. La transmisión de datos siempre se verá afectada por diversos factores que no dependen de tu equipo sino del estado de la red y otros factores que no dependen de ti. Lo ideal es que ese `setInterval` se ejecute del lado del cliente. Saludos

Comment: Buenas Mauricio contreras si, obviamente eso pensaba yo con respecto al setInterval, el problema es que ya hice dicha prueba, y ocurre lo mismo, no se, ¿que hacer realmente?, porque incluso ejemplos que he visto por internet, misteriosamente, todos usan un countdown timer pero con 5 seg o 5000 milisegundos de prueba.. osea no entiendo esto realmente :/

Comment: Es sencillo, la [latencia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latencia) es menor cuando más amplio es el lapso del intervalo. También es probable que los servidores de Discord apliquen ciertas restricciones al número de solicitudes en un rango de tiempo predeterminado. Sería bueno que revisaras el estado de la conexión de tu bot durante el lapso de interrupción del contador.

Comment: exacto @MauricioContreras cuando el lapso es mas amplio, la latencia va perfectamente, el problema es ese que igualmente como es un countdown timer, por asi decirlo, tiene que tener la latencia de 1 segundo por intervalo, mi bot yo lo coloque siempre este en "do not disturb", pero no creo que eso sea algun problema o si? incluso hace poco modifique de nuevo mi codigo, y ya no lo coloque "async" ni utilizando el "await", solo que imprimiera normalmente, y persiste el problema, por consola imprime perfecto, pero en discord, cada 5 segundos, se cuelga, y luego sigue iterando.. u.u